# condition number of rectangular matrix with epsilon

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 \epsilon & 0 & 0\\
 0 & \epsilon & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \epsilon
 \end{bmatrix}$

Find $K_2(A)$
(where $K_2(A) $ represents the condition number of the matrix with respect to $\|.\|_2$ norm. )

---

I find  $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\epsilon^3+3}$ but how find $\|A^{-1}\|_2=\|A^+\|_2$????

---

I find out that $A^+ =\frac{1}{\epsilon^4+3\epsilon^2}\begin{bmatrix} 
 {\epsilon}^2+1 & \epsilon(\epsilon^2+2) & -\epsilon & -\epsilon \\
 {\epsilon}^2+1 & -\epsilon  & \epsilon(\epsilon^2+2) & -\epsilon\\
 {\epsilon}^2+1 & -\epsilon & -\epsilon & \epsilon(\epsilon^2+2) 
 \end{bmatrix}  $

---

It's a book exercise problem. It's mentioned that this matrix is ill-conditioned .

Comment: With the regular definition of inverse , $A^{-1}$ doesn't exist for a non square matrix $A$. Maybe you are trying to use the pseudo inverse ?

Comment: Well, you could start by finding $A^{-1}$ (or more accurately, [$A^+$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)).

Comment: Okk ..... .....